# Using an app bundle I get UnsatisfiedLinkError for <1% of users

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to use the new Android App Bundles.

I run some test locally on my devices, and everything works correctly. However, once deployed to production, I am starting to see a few errors like this:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/xyz/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/xyz/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libsqlite3x.so"
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary (Runtime.java)
java.lang.System.loadLibrary (System.java)
io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<clinit> (SQLiteDatabase.java:86)
io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:241)
io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:199)
...
```

The error states that a library I'm using (requery/sqlite-android) cannot find the .so file that it needs. 
This seems strange, since I checked with bundletool, and in every APK the file .so is there.

The error happens on two devices: a Samsung Galaxy Note 7 and a 
TECNO-J8, running Android 6 and 5 respectively.

According to the Play Store, the error happens for app installed through Google Play, so I doubt the error is related to APK sideloading.

---

The generated APK bundle includes splits for the following architectures:

- splits\base-armeabi_v7a.apk
- splits\base-mips.apk
- splits\base-arm64_v8a.apk
- splits\base-x86_64.apk
- splits\base-x86.apk

Do you have any hints?

Comment: Those devices are included at any of those abi architectures?

Comment: Galaxy Note 7 has a Exynos 8890 ```The Exynos 8890 .... CPU core based on 64-bit ARMv8 architecture.``` maybe you missing a v8 plus a v8a

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I think it is included in the splits\base-arm64_v8a.apk, is it not?

Comment: Maybe, i read some problems with some armeabi-v8 not reading armv8a[]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though the installs are reported from Play, this information can easily be spoofed when using adb (which some users have learnt to do for some reason that I don't quite get yet). Those crashes very likely come from sideloads which don't install the config splits in spite of the appearances.

Comment: I guess you are right, that seems to be the only explanation

Comment: Where would someone get a bundle to create an apk to side load? AFAIK the store only ever serves apk's.

Comment: Even if they could get the bundle they'd need the signing key.

Comment: They're not getting the bundle, they are getting the APKs (originally served by Play), but they're manually installing only one APK instead of the [multiple APKs required](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#dynamic_delivery) for the app to properly function.

Comment: Now I get what you are saying. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

This issue might be related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127691101

It happens on some devices of LG or old Samsung devices where the user has moved the app to the SD Card.

One way of fixing the issue is to use Relinker library to load your native libraries instead of directly calling System.load method.

https://github.com/KeepSafe/ReLinker

Another way is to block the movement of the app to the SD card or by keeping android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false in your gradle.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

@see https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure-base#disable_config_apks

disable bundle api split can fix this bug.
add this into your build.gradle file

```
bundle {
    abi {
        // This property is set to true by default.
        enableSplit = false
    }
}
```