# Android native library (.so) - unsatisfied link error

Tags: android, c, kotlin, java-native-interface

I have recently created and published an Android App bundle with compiled native libraries for all processors architectures. On most of devices everything is running ok. But on some of devices I can see this error in Crashlytics console
**Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.someapp-wAu5DoLmLvM_RVnbU1qsCg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.someapp-wAu5DoLmLvM_RVnbU1qsCg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "somemylib.so"**

I am wondering - why this may happen. I have libs for x64 processors. This is happening only on some devices - but this crash is the most often in Crashlytics. 
All my libs are stored inside jniLibs directory
THese are some pieces from my build.gradle

```
bundle {
    density {
        // Different APKs are generated for devices with different screen densities; true by default.
        enableSplit false
    }
    abi {
        // Different APKs are generated for devices with different CPU architectures; true by default.
        enableSplit true
    }
    language {
        // This is disabled so that the App Bundle does NOT split the APK for each language.
        // We're gonna use the same APK for all languages.
        enableSplit false
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi', 'mips', 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 
 'mips64', 'x86_64'
    }
}
sourceSets {

    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
    }
}
```

I have a service class inside my app which is trying to load native library when someone is starting it. My be sometimes this "start" call to service is executing before the OS can detect the native libs in my app? But I don't think that this is so.
Can you help me please

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is not with the library code, but with the .so files themselves.
Android devices have a primary ABI, the instruction set supported by the processor.
For example, some devices with 64-bit processors use the ABI `arm64-v8a`.

However, a lot of libraries and apps don't support 64-bit processors yet. So usually, the newer processors also support a secondary ABI, which is a more common one. `arm64-v8a` processors usually support `armeabi-v7a` too, for example.

When the app starts, it starts looking for the native libraries in the directories. First it checks in the primary ABI directory, `arm64-v8a` in this example. If the .so files are not there, it checks in the secondary ABI directory (`armeabi-v7a`). If still not found, you will get the error you described.

In your case, you have the files, as you said, so that's not the problem.

One big problem with this selection is, that it always sticks to the primary ABI, if the directory exists. This can lead to crashes if not all libraries supply all .so files for all ABIs. This is described [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#aen).

Here's an example: you include 2 libraries in your app:
1. VideoPlayerLibrary, which has .so files for all ABIs
2. GifLibrary, which has .so files only for `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a`.

Now if you start the app on an `arm64-v8a` device, it will stick to it's primary ABI, because it has found files there (the .so files of VideoPlayerLibrary). But at the moment you want to play gifs, it will try to load the .so files from the `arm64-v8a` directory, but it will not find them there and it will crash as in your post with a link error.

**So what can you do?**

You have 2 options:

1. If it is your own library which has the missing .so files, compile it for all ABIs. 
   If it is not your own, check if there's a newer version which has fixed this issue.
2. Exclude the incomplete ABIs from the app. This way the newer processors will use the secondary ABI for running the app. This will result in worse performance of course, but it will not crash.
   From my experience, the most important ABI is `armeabi-v7a`, this should be supported by probably all Android devices.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have an access to all the native code. So I have compiled my native libraries for all platforms. I have checked that all .so files are present in every abi library. So we can be sure that all libs are compiled. May be the problem is the Android App bundle compilation? This issue is happening only on some ammount of x64 devices. On most of x64 devices everything is running okay. May be this be a problem of a specific device? At the current moment I have about 200 crashes per 10000 updates

Comment: Have you checked the .so files in the split release apks? Perhaps it could have been ignored during the release build process. It might also be false reporting, see this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595535/using-an-app-bundle-i-get-unsatisfiedlinkerror-for-1-of-users

Comment: I'll try to take a look at my bundle to check if all native libs are there. I haven't done this already. And I am also wondering - my be some users are able to install the bundle without Google Play. May be they are fetching apks from rooted phone and then published them somewhere and other people who are trying to install these cracked apks are running this issue?

Comment: That might be it. In Google Play crash statistics you can filter on install source (Google Play or Other), that would filter this issue out.

Comment: I was hoping that this issue was running on installation not from GP. But nope. All the issues have come form the apps installed via GooglePlay

Comment: I am missing this line in my build.gradle ndk.abiFilters = 'armeabi-v7a' 'arm64-v8a' 'x86' 'x86_64'. May be the problem is in that I don't have this line in build.gradle?

Comment: It just reduces the amount of splits, since there exist no mips, and armeabi devices anymore. It is a good way to reduce the amount of apks, or save space if you build a single one. Did you check the split apks, if they contain the correct ABI .so files?

Comment: How can I fetch splitted apks from the bundle?

Comment: Have a look at bundletool from this medium post: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/explor…

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll check and later write about my success

Comment: I've checked my bundle - all libs are there. May be the problem is in that Android OS is looking for the so in the wrong folder -/lib/arm64? Why I does not looking for it in the arm64-v8a?

Comment: /lib/arm64 looks right, something else might be the issue. I'm out of ideas, if I were you, I would try to buy or borrow a device which it crashes on, and observe the behavior with a debugger (or check the filesystem with root)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! This fixed the sporadic crashes I was seeing on various devices.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127691101

It happens on some devices of LG or old Samsung devices where the user has moved the app to the SD Card.

One way of fixing the issue is to use Relinker library to load your native libraries instead of directly calling System.load method.

https://github.com/KeepSafe/ReLinker

Another way is to block the movement of the app to the SD card.

You can also keep android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false in your gradle.properties file. But it will increase the app download size on Play Store as well as its disk size.