# Problem with flutter build apk file on real phone

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I'm new in Flutter and Android Studio. My problem - when i run my app in android studio - all works good. But, when i upload build apk file to firebase "app distribution", install on real phone and try to launch - it has crashed on start - without any error message. I see the first load screen, and that's all, app closed. I don't understand - how to debug such error, because all works, when  i use Android studio. Any ideas - how can i catch this error ?

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale ru-RU)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
```

Logcat logs

```
2020-06-27 19:34:17.653 587-644/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2020-06-27 19:34:17.655 2859-6628/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start
2020-06-27 19:34:17.665 2859-6628/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedru.rakhimyan.pozhlikbez.pozhlikbez/ru.rakhimyan.pozhlikbez.pozhlikbez.MainActivity/1
2020-06-27 19:34:17.666 2859-6628/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedru.rakhimyan.pozhlikbez.pozhlikbez/ru.rakhimyan.pozhlikbez.pozhlikbez.MainActivity/1
2020-06-27 19:34:17.674 2859-6360/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedru.rakhimyan.pozhlikbez.pozhlikbez/ru.rakhimyan.pozhlikbez.pozhlikbez.MainActivity/1
2020-06-27 19:34:17.761 24805-24812/? E/kbez.pozhlikbe: Failed to send DDMS packet REAQ to debugger (-1 of 20): Broken pipe
2020-06-27 19:34:17.777 10947-23478/? E/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
2020-06-27 19:34:18.659 24805-24805/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.rakhimyan.pozhlikbez.pozhlikbez, PID: 24805
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/ru.rakhimyan.pozhlikbez.pozhlikbez-leCXnGCESBlgFvEwD87Sfg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ru.rakhimyan.pozhlikbez.pozhlikbez-leCXnGCESBlgFvEwD87Sfg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/ru.rakhimyan.pozhlikbez.pozhlikbez-leCXnGCESBlgFvEwD87Sfg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.startInitialization(FlutterLoader.java:120)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.startInitialization(FlutterLoader.java:88)
        at io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.startInitialization(FlutterMain.java:48)
        at io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication.onCreate(FlutterApplication.java:24)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5906)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:200)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1660)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2020-06-27 19:34:18.770 4311-4326/? E/droid.launcher: No package ID ff found for ID 0xffffffff.
2020-06-27 19:34:18.772 4311-4326/? E/IconLoader: Could not find icon drawable from resource
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:225)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:887)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:827)
        at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.IconLoader.createNewIconForTask(IconLoader.java:118)
        at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.IconLoader.getAndInvalidateIfModified(IconLoader.java:94)
        at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateActivityIcon(RecentsTaskLoader.java:325)
        at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.executePlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:188)
        at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.loadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:173)
        at com.android.quickstep.RecentsModel.onTaskStackChangedBackground(RecentsModel.java:214)
        at com.android.systemui.shared.system.TaskStackChangeListeners.onTaskStackChanged(TaskStackChangeListeners.java:80)
        at android.app.ITaskStackListener$Stub.onTransact(ITaskStackListener.java:50)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
2020-06-27 19:34:18.773 4311-4326/? E/droid.launcher: Failed to open APK '/data/app/ru.rakhimyan.pozhlikbez.pozhlikbez-IGs77SWnk7PWEecGA2tGBQ==/base.apk' I/O error
2020-06-27 19:34:18.773 4311-4326/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/ru.rakhimyan.pozhlikbez.pozhlikbez-IGs77SWnk7PWEecGA2tGBQ==/base.apk
2020-06-27 19:34:19.170 2859-2939/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.android.launcher3/com.android.a1launcher.AndroidOneLauncher/28
2020-06-27 19:34:19.180 587-644/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/min_freq not supported
2020-06-27 19:34:19.180 587-644/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 0]
2020-06-27 19:34:19.181 587-644/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Failed to read /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/force_no_nap
2020-06-27 19:34:19.181 587-644/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [10, 7]
2020-06-27 19:34:19.272 563-24849/? E/msm8916_platform: platform_get_snd_device_backend_index: BE DAI Name Table is not present
2020-06-27 19:34:19.272 563-24849/? E/audio_hw_utils: send_app_type_cfg_for_device: Couldn't get the backend index for snd device voice-rec-mic ret=-14
2020-06-27 19:34:19.273 563-24849/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
2020-06-27 19:34:19.273 563-24849/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE Returned = -19
2020-06-27 19:34:19.273 563-24849/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
```

Comment: You can catch the error with logcat

Comment: Can you post your logcat in your question? It will help us decipher the problem.

Comment: Make sure that the app has all the permissions declared in AndroidManifest.xml (e.g. when it uses internet)

Comment: I have added logcat @MahirIslam

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/55136767/1860868